# Deadlock Issue: While Merge to SQL DB

Tags: azure-sql-database, deadlock

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue, in our databricks notebook code where we try to merge data into sql db , often see error -

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction was deadlocked on lock | generic waitable object resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Deadlock Issue is caused by a situation when the first transaction is waiting for the second one (to release table2) while the second transaction is also waiting the first (to release table1) one in the same time.

1. Make sure the applications access all shared objects in the same order.
2. Keep transactions short and simple.
3. Make sure the applications use the minimum necessary transaction isolation level.

Refer this [article](https://academy.sqlbak.com/transaction-process-id-was-deadlocked-on-lock-resources-with-another-process-and-has-been-chosen-as-the-deadlock-victim-msg-1205/) by Alexandr Omelchenko